# Function for global variables

Tags: java

I have some code that repeat itself which I wish to put in function. But the problem is I use global variable which I cannot send to function, any idea how to shorten my code?

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame {

private static List<JComboBox> sundayCombo;
private static List<JComboBox> mondayCombo;
private static List<JComboBox> tuesdayCombo;
private static List<JComboBox> wednesdayCombo;
private static List<JComboBox> thursdayCombo;
private static List<JComboBox> fridayCombo;
private static List<JComboBox> saturdayCombo;

public static void main(String[] args) {

sundayCombo = new ArrayList<>();
    mondayCombo = new ArrayList<>();
    tuesdayCombo = new ArrayList<>();
    wednesdayCombo = new ArrayList<>();
    thursdayCombo = new ArrayList<>();
    fridayCombo = new ArrayList<>();
    saturdayCombo = new ArrayList<>();

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainClass frame = new MainClass();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}

public MainClass() {

for (String string : mylist) {

        //Create function for the next section
        //Some thing like this:
        //createPanel(sundayCombo,panel_sunday_therapist);

        JComboBox comboBox1 = createComboBox();
        sundayCombo.add(comboBox1);
        panel_sunday_nurse.add(comboBox1);
        panel_sunday_nurse.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(STRUT_SIZE));

        JComboBox comboBox2 = createComboBox();
        mondayCombo.add(comboBox2);
        panel_monday_nurse.add(comboBox2);
        panel_monday_nurse.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(STRUT_SIZE));

        JComboBox comboBox3 = createComboBox();
        tuesdayCombo.add(comboBox3);
        panel_tuesday_nurse.add(comboBox3);
        panel_tuesday_nurse.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(STRUT_SIZE));

        JComboBox comboBox4 = createComboBox();
        wednesdayCombo.add(comboBox4);
        panel_wednesday_nurse.add(comboBox4);
        panel_wednesday_nurse.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(STRUT_SIZE));

        JComboBox comboBox5 = createComboBox();
        thursdayCombo.add(comboBox5);
        panel_thursday_nurse.add(comboBox5);
        panel_thursday_nurse.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(STRUT_SIZE));

        JComboBox comboBox6 = createComboBox();
        fridayCombo.add(comboBox6);
        panel_friday_nurse.add(comboBox6);
        panel_friday_nurse.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(STRUT_SIZE));

        JComboBox comboBox7 = createComboBox();
        saturdayCombo.add(comboBox7);
        panel_saturday_nurse.add(comboBox7);
        panel_saturday_nurse.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(STRUT_SIZE));


    }

    }

private JComboBox createComboBox() {

    //bla bla
    return comboBox;
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe statics are not the best choice here.

Comment: But I have to use static due to main is static

Comment: No, you don't have to. You can instantiate the `MainClass` in the `main` method.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: You mean an example of calling `new MainClass();` in your `main` method?

Comment: But I do so... I am calling MainClass() in main. Not? At EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()

Comment: Ah, yes. Then I don't understand why these lists have to be static.

Comment: And parallel lists is definitely The Wrong Thing. Map, array, enum, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that takes the combo box that you wish to  add to as the argument for the function, i.e.

```
private void addComboBox(List<JComboBox> weekdayCombo, JPanel weekdayPanel) {
    ComboBox comboBox1 = createComboBox();
    weekdayCombo.add(comboBox1);
    weekdayPanel.add(comboBox1);
    weekdayPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(STRUT_SIZE));
}
```

and you can call the function as `addComboBox(sundayCombo, panel_sunday_nurse)`

Comment: But when passing global variable to function it passed by value and not reference...

Comment: @Dim Java is always pass by value, it does not matter. The value will still be added to one of your static lists.